# Which servers require an enterprise license for event-based pull replication?

Tags: artifactory

I am looking to utilize event-based [pull replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication#RepositoryReplication-PullReplication) between two Artifactory servers.

My question is, which of the two servers requires the Enterprise license? Is it just the destination server that is doing the pulling replication that requires the Enterprise license? Can the source server be a lesser license like OSS or Pro?

Answer (score 1):

For using event-based pull replication between two Artifactory servers, the target server is the server that most have an Enterprise license.
By target server we refer to the server that you enable the event-based pull replication checkbox at.
However, it would not work pulling from the OSS version even if the target has Enterprise license, as replication with remote open-source Artifactory instance is not possible.
One the artifact is replicated, you should see it at the (remote-repo-name)-cache repository